# iPhone - creating the smoothest curve

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, math

I have this iPhone app that has an array containing around 50 to 100 points. How do I calculate the smoothest curve that will fit the points? It can be bezier, cubic, quadratic, whatever. It just have to look smooth and fit as much as possible all points (obviously, as I did in my drawing, to create a smooth curve, some points have to be created out of the original set... no problem).

See picture:
[image]

Comment: Well, MathOverflow is a website for research mathematicians. Its value is that mathematicians use it professionally; it couldn't possibly work if questions not of interest to the community kept cropping up.  Imagine getting chemistry questions on StackOverflow. You could ask your math questions at [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) (which *is* for everyone), but here on Stack Overflow is also fine.

Comment: yes, I know, but some people keep recommending it every time I post a math question.

Comment: "How do I calculate the smoothest (bezier, quadratic, cubic, etc.) curve that will fit the points?" — well, what kind of curve do you want? Do you want the smoothest quadratic curve *and* the smoothest cubic curve *and* … etc.?

Comment: any kind that looks smooth and fits the original points nicely. Obviously to do that, the curve may have to create other intermediary points, as I did in my drawing (notice that the smoothed curve I drawn do not passes exactly on all points)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a Cubic Spline
[Cubic Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29)

These are the functions with continous second derivative that interpolate your nodes with the smallest curvature so they oscillate less. And there are lots of examples and algorithms to find these.

Comment: my math is a little rusty... I will try to figure out how to do that... can this be used with any number of points? In the mean time, if you can please point me to a practical example... :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can find some library or piece of code that can do the work for you. I can't link to you or write something because I don't know Objective C and how development on iOS works with libraries, sorry. Yes you can have any number of points. Try to don't reinvent the wheel because I think that it's often used also in software development. I've written because I know of this propriety thanks to my math background but I don't know when or where it's used in fact.